# Datastage- Loop throught the file to read email ID and send email

Tags: datastage

I have to read Input file to get email id of employees and send each employee email.
How can I do this using Datastage job?
File looks like this,
PERSON_ID|FName|LName|Email_ID

Answer (score 1):

DataStage itself offers a Notification Stage which is only available at the Sequence level.
As your information is in the data stream of a job you could use a [Wrapped Stage](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=jobs-defining-wrapped-stages) in order to send the mail from within a job.
A wrapped stage allows to call a OS command for each row in your stream. Sendmail etc. could be used to send the mails like you wish.

I have implemented this recently. The wrapped stage is tricky so I would recommend to use it in a very simple way - use it to call the bash (or any other shell) and prepare the mail command upfront and simply send it to that stage.

Comment: wrapped stage option looks good but little complicated. I chose to write a quick script to read file data and send email in loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are some more options.

First is using the Wrapped Stage like Michael mentioned. Another method is writing a Parallel Routine to use in an ordinary parallel transformer, which is quite similar.

---

The simplest way of sending an email per row *that I know of* is using a **server routine** in a transformer.

> Drawback is that server routines are deprecated and we're not yet sure
> how well they can be migrated to future versions of DataStage (CP4D).
> This should be considerd when doing this.

In each project you should have a folder `Routines/Built-In/Utilities` containing the server routines `DSSendMailAttachmentTester` and `DSSendMailTester`. These are originally meant to be used in the Routine Editor just for testing the backend wether it's actually able to send mail.

But you can also use them in a Transformer as well, **as long as it's a BASIC Transformer**. That means you can either write a server job using all old school stuff (which is probably not what you want), or you can use the [BASIC Transformer](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=data-basic-transformer-stage) in a parallel job. *(Follow the link on how to enable it.)* It gives access to BASIC transforms and functions.

I suggest copying the mentioned server routines to make your own custom one and maybe modify it to your needs.